# Access CouchDB from javascript

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I would like to access CouchDB (Cloudant) from an HTML5 application ... I know that there is a script hosted in the couchdb installation which I can include (overcomes cross site scripting restrictions) which will allow me to connect to the database and insert / retrieve data, but I cannot find examples of how to do this anywhere.

How can I access my database from an HTML5/JavaScript application?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [article](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/) which explains jQuery [plugin](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/jquery.couch.js) API included in CouchDB.